# Segue stops working after first segue

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, xcode7

I am trying to use a custom segue, that makes the view 'scroll' to the right or left, when a button is clicked. I added a custom class that looks like this

```
class horizontalSegue : UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {

    var oldView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView
    var newView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView

    oldView.window?.insertSubview(newView, aboveSubview: oldView)

    newView.center.x = oldView.center.x + oldView.frame.width
    newView.center.y = oldView.center.y

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: { newView.center =     oldView.center }, completion:  { finished in Void })
}
```

}

but the problem is that after I segue once, I cannot segue back to the view I segued from. I think its because of the way I have the oldView and newView declared, the app isn't updating which view is which, so its segueing back to the current view when I try to segue to the first view.
If I am correct, how would I make sure the app updates which view is which?

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation says: "Regardless of how you perform the animation, at the end of it, you are responsible for installing the destination view controller (and its views) in the right place so that it can handle events. For example, if you were to implement a custom modal transition, you might perform your animations using snapshot images and then at the end call the presentModalViewController:animated: method (with animations disabled) to set up the appropriate modal relationship between the source and destination view controllers."

May be you should add something like

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO]
```

into your animation's completion handler?

Comment: Thats not working, 'self doesn't have a property 'navigationController''. Could you elaborate what you mean? Or did that work in earlier versions of Xcode/works with objective-c? It does not work with Swift.